# Floating Action Button isn't visualized on RecyclerView. How?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, floating-action-button

I want put a FAB on a RecyclerView to add more items but only show de RecyclerView without FAT or anything I put here. This is my code:

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/lista"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/btnAnadir"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_add_white_24dp"
    app:borderWidth="0dp"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|center"
    android:layout_gravity="right" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `FrameLayout` instead of `LinearLayout` as your root layout.